# Problems with Intel graphics card

Tags: graphics

I've got a problem with my graphics card. In Windows XP my graphics card is shown as *size: 256MB*, but in Windows 7 it is shown as *size: 64MB*, and I can't run some games. I want an explanation. Thank you.

Comment: What do you want an explanation for exactly? The size you are seeing is meaningless and probably has nothing to do with why you can't run some games. (At least, this is the most likely explanation. It's hard to be sure without knowing what graphics card you have.)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're talking about the video memory size. Intel GPUs dynamically allocate RAM as video memory, so the amount used can change. It's a good thing if Windows 7 is using less memory when GPU load is low. This is by design and problems with running some games is probably unrelated.

You can ask separate question about the games problems, then we'll try to solve them.